# Apache Flink Installation 1.6.2 on Mac with Homebrew

Tags: macos, apache-flink

I am trying to use Apache Flink for the first time for a school project, but I'm running into some trouble after installation. I have tried to follow the Quicksetup on the site, but I keep running into the same problem. 
(https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/quickstart/setup_quickstart.html)

[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUow3.png)

The brew installation seems to work fine, this is where I ran into the first inconsistency however. Next the guide tells me to execute the following line

$ ./bin/start-cluster.sh  # Start Flink

which doesn't work without installing a binary from here though 
https://flink.apache.org/downloads.html

So I did that (I downloaded the Flink 1.6.2 with Hadoop 2.7 binary) and was then able to find the file and execute it. After doing this I'm supposed to go the the web frontend, and verify that a task is running. However when I go there nothing is shown. 
[Console Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZDjE.png)
[Web Dashbord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oNpR6.png)

I started by executing the stop-cluster file, because for some reason I'm constantly getting the INFO Message

[INFO] 1 instance(s) of standalonesession are already running on Moritzs-MBP.fritz.box.

So far I have tried to to look into the flink-conf.yaml file which does set the numberOfTaskSlots to 1, so the problem does not seem to lie there. Otherwise I didn't really know where to look from there however and only tried to uninstall the and reinstall everything with no results however.

Sorry that the images are not shown, previously I had been able to fix all my code problems with existing posts and thus I can't directly post them yet. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance,

Moritz

Answer (score 3):

By using brew installation, the **start-cluster.sh** should be able to found in:
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.6.2/libexec/bin

Comment: `brew info apache-flink` instead will be better to get the location

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why start-cluster.sh isn't succeeding in starting up a taskmanager, but you can always (try to) start another one by hand with

```
$ ./bin/taskmanager.sh start
```

Comment: Thanks, but sadly it also doesn't show anything as running or similar. :/